# What does the round brackets"()"-overloading mean in this example

Tags: c++, multithreading, operator-overloading

I'm a rookie in C++. I learn a simple example (see the code below). I can not undersand what is the purpose of the overloading "()". Is the "overloading ()" used in  `std::thread my_thread(my_func);`?

Thank for all your attention.

```
struct func
{
 int& i;
 func(int& i_) : i(i_) {}
 **void operator() ()** // the question point
 {
 for (unsigned j=0 ; j<1000000 ; ++j)
 {
   do_something(i);           
 }
}
};
void oops()
{
 int some_local_state=0;
 func my_func(some_local_state);
 std::thread my_thread(my_func);
 my_thread.detach();          
 }
```

Comment: I understand this to be overloading the functional operator. So you can sort of turn an instance of an object into a function. Also known as the overloading the parenthesis operator. This might help identify the right tutorials, good luck!

Comment: Search the web for the term "functor" or "function object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `func my_func(some_local_state);`, 
you could now call `my_func();` like it
was a function (instead of something like `my_func.dosomething();`), and the loop in
the operator function will be executed.

`std::thread` uses it that way (for whatever reason, the creators just liked it).
So without an `operator()`, your object makes no sense for `std::thread`

Comment: (btw., I know that one reason is to make functor stuff similar to real function calls. Still doesn´t change the fact that there is no "technical" reason, the C++ standard comitee just liked it that way)

Comment: It allows std::thread to be created with anything which is "callable", without having particular variations for free functions, member functions, lambdas, etc.